# PHP shutdown: Can't write files?

Tags: php, logging, shutdown

I'm using a Log class to store messages during execution, and then it is supposed to write these messages to a file on shutdown (with register_shutdown_function).

But for some reason, I'm always getting "file_put_contents failed to open stream: No such file or directory". It shouldn't be a problem that the file doesn't exist, file_put_contents should create the file. In fact, everything works just fine if I do the write during execution (ie: before the shutdown function is called).

Is this a php bug?

Comment: Yes agree with @konforce. Please find http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php#61185

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you use an absolute path. Relative paths aren't guaranteed to work in the shutdown function.

Comment: That really helped me out! Thanks