# open file in registered shutdown function php

Tags: php, function, fopen, shutdown

I want to log some information when the script ends, so I thought of using `register_shutdown_function`, can someone explain me why this works:

```
<?php
//register_shutdown_function('on_exit');
on_exit(); //FUNCTION on_exit CALLED NORMALLY
function on_exit(){
$path = './myfolder/myfile';
$fo = fopen($path,'w+');
fwrite($fo,"Test");
fclose($fo);
}
?>
```

and this does not:

```
<?php
register_shutdown_function('on_exit'); //FUNCTION on_exit CALLED FROM SHUTDOWN FUNCTION
//on_exit();
function on_exit(){
$path = './myfolder/myfile';
$fo = fopen($path,'w+');
fwrite($fo,"Test");
fclose($fo);
}
?>
```

returning

```
Warning: fopen(./myfolder/myfile): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 6

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 7

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 8
```

Comment: See [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php#59300) in the manual.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write to file with register\_shutdown\_function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861606/write-to-file-with-register-shutdown-function) and also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242534/php-shutdown-cant-write-files) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384308/php-file-put-contents-doesnt-work-as-expected-within-in-register-shutdown-funct) ... you get the idea.

Comment: @PatrickQ thanks for asking and thanks for the answer